# Failing to evaluate whether a method exists in a class and unsure why

Tags: php, class

I have the following block of code:

```
public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname)
{
    $SP = new RegistrationProceduresModel($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname);

    // Sanitize all the incoming data
    $sanitized = array_map(array($this, 'sanitize'), $_POST);

    if(method_exists($SP, $SP->$sanitized['function']()))
    {
        $SP->$this->$sanitized['function']();
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $val = isset($sanitized['function']) ? $sanitized['function'] . " does not exist in model."  : "was not specified";

            die("Function " . $val);
        }
        catch(exception $ex)
        {
            die("Threw an error after failing to evaluate whether a $_POST method exists. Review controller. " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public function sanitize($input)
{
    return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
}
```

The intent of which is to take some post data, check if a method exists within a class, and if so, execute it.

Unfortunately, when I run this I'm receiving the following error and I'm unsure why:

> Function getFormList does not exist in model.

I've checked the model and my function definitely exists, and is public - what else could be causing me to reach this point?

Comment: shouldn't function getFormList be public since it's being instantiated in another class's constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to do with the following line `method_exists($SP, $SP->$sanitized['function']())` maybe you mean `method_exists($SP, $sanitized['function'])`. In the first case, the function is being called, and its result being passed in.

Comment: Sorry - it is, slip of the keyboard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
method_exists($SP, $SP->$sanitized['function']);
```

to

```
method_exists($SP, $sanitized['function']);
```